# PHP Only Returning Last JSON Object

Tags: php, json

I'm attempting to do something I've done many times before (access objects in a JSON file with PHP) and for some reason `json_decode` is only returning the last item in the JSON array. Here's the JSON:

```
{
  "person": {
    "lname": "smith",
    "fname": "bob"
  },
  "person": {
    "lname": "jones",
    "fname": "jane"
  }
}
```

And the PHP:

```
<?php

//access and dump
$json = file_get_contents('people.json');
$filey = json_decode($json, true);

var_dump($filey);

?>
```

The result is only the last item in the array:

```
array (size=1)
  'person' => 
    array (size=2)
      'lname' => string 'jones' (length=5)
      'fname' => string 'jane' (length=4)
```

Using `json_last_error` returns no errors and I'm valid according to jsonlint. I'm also not finding any console errors when I load the page.

I'm totally stumped and can't see anything different from the times I've done this before - can anyone identify what I'm missing here?

Comment: Your key is same `person` so it is getting overwritten

Comment: note that keys / properties must be unique

Comment: Your indexes are same and that's why it's over-written (`person`)

Comment: You don't even need object names in this case. Take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because your json object names "person" within json array are similar so json decode will override the values with latest.
Consider something like

```
{
  "person1": {
    "lname": "smith",
    "fname": "bob"
  },
  "person2": {
    "lname": "jones",
    "fname": "jane"
  }
}
```

and your code will work fine.

Comment: Well that's embarrassing - in the past, I haven't used object names and that's why I never realized they needed to be unique. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Marcatectura, I know you've already accepted the answer that suggests using different object keys but I thought you should know. If you want an array in PHP, You don't even need object names. The following JSON will do:

```
[
    {
        "lname": "Dawes",
        "fname": "April"
    },
    {
        "lname": "Colin",
        "fname": "Dick"
    }
]
```

A trick I use when I'm designing my JSON is to build a sample PHP array in the shape I want `json_decode` to give me, encode that array and output the result to screen. So what I posted above is the result of:

```
$arr = [
    ['lname'=>'Dawes','fname'=>'April'],['lname'=>'Colin','fname'=>'Dick'],
];
$json = json_encode($arr);
echo $json;
```

Since I built a JSON by encoding an array having the shape I want, I can be confident that even as my data change, `json_decode($json,true)` will give me the array shape I expect.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `json_decode(true)`, your json is now an array. 
You cannot have two array keys that are the same, in this case "person".

If you still want to use `json_decode(true)`, then change "person" to "person1" or so.

Try both `var_dump($filey)` and `var_dump($json)`, you will see what I'm talking about.